# упаковщики tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Почему через `pack()` отображаются кнопки, а через `place()` - нет?

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainApplication:
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent)
        self.but_student = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Student", width=25, command=self.student_window)
        self.window3 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Window 2", font="Serene 10", fg='white', bg='black').place(x=100, y=340)
        self.window4 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Window 3", fg='white', bg='black', font="Serene 10").place(x=250, y=340)
        self.window5 = tk.Button(self.frame, fg='white', bg='black', text="Window 4", font="Serene 10").place(x=400, y=340)
        self.but_student.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def student_window(self):
        self.this_student = tk.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.app = Window2(self.this_student)

    def window3(self):
        self.window_3 = tk.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.app2 = Window3(self.window_3)


class Window2:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent)
        self.info_student = tk.Label(self.frame, text='Севрук Артем\n'
                                                      'група ІВ-71\n'
                                                      'номер у списку 19\n'
                                                      'варіант {}'.format(self.variant(71, 19)), font="Arial 17 bold").pack(fill='both')
        self.frame.pack()

    def variant(self, g, n):
        return (n + g % 60) % 30 + 1


class Window3:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent)


#class Window4(tk.Frame):

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не сделали размер вашего `Frame`
Исправленная часть кода

```
class MainApplication:
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent, width=500, height=400)
.......
```

P.s не используйте несколько компоновщиков т.к. может это привести так же как в данной ситуации потому что у вас, по мимо размера `Frame` у вас все равно не будет отображаться данный кнопки, но если поменять `self.but_student.pack()` на `self.bit_studet.place(x=0, y=0)`, то будет все нормально.